# TrueCrypt disk encryption causes extremely slow Windows startup

Tags: windows, boot, encryption, truecrypt

I have a Windows desktop that was fast on startup until I encrypted the hard disk with TrueCrypt. Now it takes maybe around 3 minutes to startup after I type in my key. Then when my desktop appears, it still takes a while before I can even do anything. All normal operations are slow from then on. From the time I type in my key to the time I can just open my firefox is about 6 minutes, sometimes more.

Specs:

Windows 7 Home Premium
AMD Phenom II Quad-Core
8GB RAM
300GB SATA HDD.

This computer was re-purposed into a banking only computer so I don't do anything demanding but it just drags. Nothing is set to startup at boot other than my antivirus. Since I don't play games or do anything special on it, is there anything I can do to speed it up by disabling certain unneeded features/services? Already did away with the Aero thing. This was a fresh reinstall once I re-purposed it and then added the encryption. System is clean with no malware and this is a legitimate Windows install from a Microsoft disc. I would like somewhat of a barebones Windows setup. Thanks.

Comment: Your CPU is really old. Do you know if it supports the AES instruction set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)? What encryption algorithm(s) are you using? Also, fyi, truecrypt has been discontinued.

Comment: If you decrypt the drive (or revert from an image, if you have one), you can create TrueCrypt *folders*. The system should boot as normal, and your encrypted folders with data should open quickly. Downside: you'll have to manually start TrueCrypt after Windows loads and open then folders.

Comment: With 8GB of ram and a quad-core, you could run a live linux in RAM all day long, and not even worry about encrypting a whole drive since everything will either be read-only (from the DVD or USB) or in RAM (live linux's store files in an overlayfs & tmpfs in ram, lost at shutdown). You can save some settings, like your web browser profile folder, you could zip & encrypt it to save on disk, loading at startup & saving at shutdown. And Bonus: linux is immune to the standard Windows viruses/malware. I've heard some companies recommend such a setup specifically for banking-type applications.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I found out my CPU does not support AES so that's probably where it's lagging since I'm using AES. I knew about TrueCrypt being discontinued and was going to look into other options. I was thinking of a Linux VM or something. I like the idea of the Live Linux but I do want to store some personal information safely on the computer. I'll have to look into some different options. Thanks again :)